# tool bar not removed?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

So im trying to remove my tool bar on android design page but can't for some reason.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide futher informations. Your question is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the theme of your **Activity** in your **Manifest** without an **ActionBar**?

In **styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Then in your design page, you'll need to select the theme you just created in the dialog.

Comment: Getting an error; Cannot resolve symbol "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

Comment: You need to define AppTheme.NoActionBar in **styles.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Add this in manifest file

```
  <application
        ...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
        ...
    </application>
```